# Generate dynamic query without stored procedure teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

First table:

```
+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| TableId | TableName              | DatabaseName 
+---------+------------------------+-----------+
|       1 | test                   |      mydb |
+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

Second table:

```
+--------------------------------+
| ColID TableId ColName DataType |                        
+--------------------------------+
| 1       1      Amount  Numeric                       
| 2       1      Name    String  |                        
+--------------------------------+
```

Query

```
SELECT *
    (CASE data_type          
        WHEN  'NUMERIC' THEN 'SUM'
        WHEN  'STRING' THEN 'LENGTH'
     END)  Operation_Performed,
    (CASE data_type          
        WHEN  'NUMERIC' THEN  (select sum(ColName ) from  FirstTable.DatabaseName.FirstTable.TableName)
        WHEN  'STRING' THEN (select length(ColName )  from FirstTable.DatabaseName.FirstTable.TableName)
    END)  Output
FROM 
    FirstTable tab 
INNER JOIN
    SecondTable col ON tab.table_id = col.table_id
```

In the second case statement in then clause i need to make values dynamic but its not parsing.

Is there any other approach? I can't use a stored procedure.

Comment: What is your desire approach?

Comment: i want to create a generic query ....i dont have permission for stored proc

Comment: select sum(colname) from  FirstTable.DatabaseName.FirstTable.TableName

Comment: I am stuck in second case statement then query...how do i pass values there..

Comment: Dynamic SQL can only be done in a Stored Procedure. Of course you can write a Select constructing the SQL you want like this: `select 'select ' || CASE data_type          
        WHEN  'NUMERIC' THEN  'sum'
        WHEN  'STRING' THEN 'length' END|| '('  columnname || ') from ' || FirstTable.DatabaseName || '.' || FirstTable.TableName || ';' FROM FirstTable ...` and then execute this.

Comment: thanks..one more thing if i have max(length(col)) case how should I handle

Comment: Modify the CASE locic to add the additional `)` or use nested CASEs  :-)

Comment: could pls elaborate..iam not able to execute ..thanks @dnoeth

Comment: `CASE data_type WHEN 'NUMERIC' THEN 'sum('|| columnname || ')' WHEN 'STRING' THEN 'max(char_length('|| columnname || '))' END || ' from ' || FirstTable.DatabaseName ||`